# В чем разница между Func<> и delegate?

Tags: c#

Оба варианта используются с целью возвращения значения, оба могут принимать несколько параметров.
В чем между ними разница?

Comment: а с переменным количеством параметров бывают делегаты?

Comment: Ну если только вы будете использовать параметр-массив с модификатором params, но, строго говоря, это не является переменным числом аргументов. Можно еще вспомнить про слово __arglist, но это скорее любопытная информация, нежели нечто полезное.

Comment: @Andrew, не нужно ставить метку c#-faq на всё подряд, `Func<>` не является частью языка c#

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Ну, есть ключевое слово `delegate` — это описание сигнатуры функции, т. е., её списка параметров и типа возвращаемого значения. Используется так:

```
public delegate bool MyPredicate(int x);
```

Им можно пользоваться так:

```
private bool IsOdd(int i) { return i % 2 != 0; }

private Analyze(MyPredicate p, int x)
{
    bool result = p(x);
    if (result)
        Console.WriteLine("found!");
}

Analyze(IsOdd, 1); // печатает "found!"
```

С другой стороны, есть готовые, предопределённые сигнатуры функций (`Func<TArg1, TArg2, ..., TResult>` с возвращаемым значением, `Action<TArg1, Targ2, ...>` без). То есть, можно не определять делегат самому, а воспользоваться готовыми `Func` и `Action`. Аналогичный пример:

```
private bool IsOdd(int i) { return i % 2 != 0; }

private Analyze(Func<int, bool> p, int x)
{
    bool result = p(x);
    if (result)
        Console.WriteLine("found!");
}

Analyze(IsOdd, 1); // печатает "found!"
```

Если для вашей сигнатуры подходит `Func` или `Action`, особого смысла определять свой делегат нету. Или есть, если вы хотите дать своему делегату более подходящее имя, чем просто `Func`, и хотите подчеркнуть его *семантику*.

Существуют случаи, когда свой делегат всё же необходимо объявлять. Например, наличие `out`- и `ref`-параметров:

```
public delegate Updater(ref int x); // невозможно выразить через Func
```

---

Для полноты, вот (надеюсь, полный) список вариантов, когда вам придётся объявлять делегат:

- Когда список аргументов чересчур длинный (для .NET 4+ более 16 аргументов, для .NET 3.5 больше 4 аргументов)
- Когда ваши аргументы содержат `ref`, `out` или `params`.
- Если ваш делегат рекурсивен (например `delegate D D(D d)`). Как ни странно, такие штуки [иногда нужны](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_combinator).
- Если вы хотите дать «говорящие» имена аргументам вашего делегата (аргументы `Action`/`Func` называются `arg1`, `arg2` и т. д.).

Comment: На счет out и ref спасибо, специфично. Столкнусь - буду знать, что применить

Comment: @alex91: пожалуйста!

Comment: Добавлю. Еще свои делегаты нужны, когда есть параметры с совпадающими типами, но разным значением. Потому что очень сложно понять, что же такое вообще делает делегат `Func<MyClass, MyClass, object>` :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Угу, это разница по существу между номинальной и структурной системой типов (не уверен, что перевёл правильно _nominal_ и _structural_). Вот ещё по теме: http://blog.coverity.com/2014/06/18/delegates-structural-identity/

Answer (score 6):

А вы вообще уверены, что правильно понимаете, что такое делегат? Так вот, делегат в c#  - это такая сущность, которая может представлять собой некий метод. Можно сказать, что делегат определяет сигнатуру метода и его возвращаемое значение. (а можно также сказать, что делегат - это такой указатель на функцию, как, скажем, в С++, но с некотрыми оговорками).

Так вот Func (и любая его разновидность в том  числе) - это всего лишь разновидность делегата. То есть любой Func - делегат, но не любой делегат - Func и сравнивать их не очень уместно.
А что касается этого:

> Оба используются я целью возвращения значения, оба могут принимать несколько параметров

то вот вам пример делегата, который не принимает аргументов и не возвращает значений:

```
    delegate void SomeDelegate();
```

Comment: г-н минусатор, вы с чем-то не согласны? Буду рад услышать вашу (бесспорно) весомо аргументированную точку зрения

Comment: нет, мне просто ответ не понравился.

>любой Func - делегат

>не любой делегат - Func

>сравнивать их не очень уместно

что? почему бы как раз не задаться вопросом, почему же не любой делегат - Func

>то вот вам delegate void SomeDelegate();

то вот вам Action, что из одной оперы с Func.

>(бесспорно)
да ладно вам, одним минусом больше, одним меньше

Comment: на минус в общем-то по фигу, это вы правы. Но с вашими замечаниями не соглашусь: 

>почему бы как раз не задаться вопросом, почему же не любой делегат - Func

хотя бы потому, что Func - всего лишь вид делегата. Поэтому не всякий делегат есть Func - все вроде бы прозрачно

>то вот вам Action, что из одной оперы с Func.

про Action тут ни слова - автор напрямую сравнивал делегаты и Func
Ну и собственно, в-третьих, я сакцентировал внимание на том, что ТС не совсем верно понимает, что есть делегат. Еси не ошибаюсь, против истины я тут нигде не погрешил

Comment: >хотя бы потому

почему еще?

>все вроде бы прозрачно
>делегат определяет сигнатуру метода и его возвращаемое значение

Func тоже определяет сигнатуру метода и его возвращаемое значение

так в чем разница то? (...спросил ТС, а в ответ ему последовало: "вы не понимаете"). То что вы показали, что делегат может вести себя как Action, это как показать различие между Action и Func, вопрос то был не в этом.

>против истины

ну тут у вас истина получилась в том, что ТС не знает и задал вопрос - это из раздряда КО.

Comment: Не вижу причины для спора, человек дал достаточно хороший ответ:)

Comment: В любом случае, мне кажется, минусующий обязан откомментировать свою оценку, хотя бы для того, чтобы другие участники сайта понимали, в чём потенциальная проблема с ответом. За исключением редких случаев, кода проблема самоочевидна (спам, самореклама и фсё такоэ).

Comment: petya извините, но вы занимаетесь придирательством к словам и демагогией. Action тут вы приплели сами. Я же высказал одну очевидную мысль - Func всего лишь подвид делегата. Если у вас есть своя правильная, на ваш взгляд, точка зрения, то добро пожаловать в ответ

Answer (score 5):

Если посмотреть описание Func то он является дженерик делегатом

```
namespace System
{
    /// <summary>Инкапсулирует метод с одним параметром и возвращает значение типа, указанного в параметре <paramref name="TResult" />.</summary>
    /// <returns>Возвращаемое значение метода, инкапсулируемого данным делегатом.</returns>
    /// <param name="arg">Параметр метода, инкапсулируемого данным делегатом.</param>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Тип параметра метода, инкапсулируемого данным делегатом.Этот параметр типа является контрвариантным. Это означает, что можно использовать либо указанный тип, либо менее производный тип. Дополнительные сведения о ковариации и контрвариации см. в разделе Ковариация и контравариация в универсальных шаблонах.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TResult">Тип возвращаемого значения метода, инкапсулируемого данным делегатом.Этот параметр типа является ковариантным. Это означает, что можно использовать либо указанный тип, либо более производный тип. Дополнительные сведения о ковариации и контрвариации см. в разделе Ковариация и контравариация в универсальных шаблонах.</typeparam>
    /// <filterpriority>2</filterpriority>
    [__DynamicallyInvokable, TypeForwardedFrom("System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089")]
    public delegate TResult Func<in T, out TResult>(T arg);
}
```

Использование Func удобнее нежели каждый раз объявлять конкретный делегат, а так как он находится в mscorlib.dll то доступен из всех сборок.