# Именование аргуметов Action

Tags: c#

```
public event Action<string, int, int> Changed;
```

Если у `Action` два и более аргументов одного типа, в большинстве случаев это не понятное уродство. Остаётся либо писать

`<summary> T2: old value, T3: new value </summary>`,

либо заворачивать в `struct`.

При генерации метода под это событие выходит:

```
private void OnChange (string arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

А случаем нет каких нибудь опций указать имена аргументам `Action`?

Comment: Настоящего способа нет, но можно попробовать использовать ValueTuple, правда, выглядеть это будет громоздко: `Action<(string arg1, int arg2, int arg3)>`

Comment: а чего бы вместо этого не юзать обычный EnventHandler с указанием вашего класса EventArgs ?

Comment: Но правильный способ — оборачивать это в нормальный класс, для событий обычно наследуют его от EventArgs

Comment: Только хотел оформить ответом про EventArgs, и тут уже комментов накидали)

Comment: @aepot, никогда не поздно написать ответ, если люди (я) пишут комментарий, то они не собираются писать ответ. Но он должен быть

Comment: То есть опций нет . А жаль, ссылка на sender не всегда нужна, а у `Action` довольно короткий ситаксис, а с `ValueTuple` действительно выглядит стрёмно. Тогда буду `EventArgs` писать. Всем спасибо.

Comment: @АндрейNOP: по поводу tuple, вот если ещё реализуют [splatting](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/1654)...

Comment: @VladD ловите функциональщика! :) <попутно пописывая свою апишечку на Erlang>

Comment: @VladD, насчёт Auto не уверен, что это хорошо, но синтаксис для splatting'а нужен точно. В б-гомерзком js он уже достаточно давно есть :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Например, можно отказаться от предопределённого `Action<>`, воспользоваться кастомным делегатом:

```
public delegate void ChangedEvent(string name, int oldValue, int newValue);

public class C
{
    public event ChangedEvent Changed;
}
```

При создании обработчика Студия предложит нужные имена:

[image: как-то так]

Comment: Тоже вариант, плюсик поставил, но как по мне `Action` выглядит как-то привычнее что-ли. Да и каждый разраб знает, что `Action` - это делегат, а если `ChangedEvent` написать, с ходу не понятно, что это делегат, особенно если он определен где-то в другом месте. Но да, F12 никто не отменял.

Comment: ЛОЛ, настолько редко пишу, когда нужен возвращаемы тип, что забыл напрочь с этими экшенами. 

Comment: Заодно добавил этот пункт [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/204945/10105).

Comment: Хотя вру, не забыл, подумав о делегате, как раз тут-же и пришла мысль, о возможном существовании опций нейминга аргументов для Action, поскольку сам его смысл, не писать кастумные делегаты для void.

Comment: @Yaroslav а для не-`void` есть `Func` :)

Comment: @aepot, редко пользуюсь делегатом с возвращаемым типом и каждый раз когда пользуюсь чувствую, что говнокодю, из за чего про `Func` не знал и не очень хочу знать :). F12 не отменяли и [Naming Conventions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/naming-conventions-delegates-and-event-handlers).

Comment: @Yaroslav ну если в `Func` не знакомы, то есть [вот такое колдунство](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1300322/373567) для примера.

Comment: @aepot, не, не нужно мне ваше нелегальное колдовство, в `StartCoroutine` не засунешь `Func<IEnumerator>` .

Comment: @Yaroslav ну я больше про то, что оно просто есть, а не про то что оно вам вот срочно прямо сейчас надо.

Comment: @aepot, да не я просто стебусь. Я всё понимаю.

Comment: @aepot: _Да и каждый разраб знает, что Action - это делегат_ — ага, меня всё время пугают `ThreadStart` и `ParametrizedThreadStart`, хотя уже пора бы привыкнуть.

Answer (score 7):

`Action` - это просто делегат, имеющий кучу обобщенных перегрузок. Есть и другой делегат - `EventHandler`.

```cs
public delegate void Action<in T1, in T2, in T3>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3);
public delegate void EventHandler<TEventArgs>(object? sender, TEventArgs e);
```

Для обработчиков событий принято использовать именно второй. Но это конечно не обязательно означает, что это нужно делать. Например, если вам ну совсем не нужен `sender`, то можно использовать.

```cs
public delegate void Action<in T>(T obj);
```

Использовать ли при этом `EventArgs` как базовый класс для передачи данных или нет - тоже дело индивидуальное.

Что такое `EventArgs` - [а вот что](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/EventArgs.cs).

```cs
public class EventArgs
{
    public static readonly EventArgs Empty = new EventArgs();

    public EventArgs()
    {
    }
}
```

Есть ли смысл от него наслодоваться именно в Unity - я думаю нет. От него наследуются в обычных десктопных приложениях, чтобы посредством культуры разработки дать другим разработчикам возможность легче читать код.

Получается, что классного, крутого решения вашей проблемы нет, придется заворачивать аргументы либо в `struct`, либо в `Tuple`, либо в `class`, либо в `record` (но я не знаю, доступны ли записи в Unity для использования).

---

Отсюда варианты

```cs
Action<(string arg1, int arg2, int arg3)>
```

Кортежи удобны тем, что их на лету можно собирать, разбирать и пересобирать. И хранить собранный кортеж в одной переменной. Здесь рекомендую смотреть подробнее с практической точки зрения, как вам удобнее.

Либо так.

```cs
Action<MyArgsType>
```

Где `MyArgsType` например

```
public struct MyArgsType
{
    public string arg1;
    public int arg2;
    public int arg3;
}
```

К сожалению, другие варианты решить этот ребус мне неизвестны.

Comment: И даже про Unity упомянул, как об особой зоне (отщипенцев , чей мрачный код никто всё равно не увидит ). Одобряю 